# ngrx/data- How can I write custom reducers to handle endpoint returning multiple entities?

Tags: ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I am currently trying to convert my ngrx store to use ngrx/data to handle my entities.  One of the trickier obstacles I have hit is handling API endpoints that return data for multiple entities.  A simple example- lets say I have the following models that can be retrieved from my API:

```js
export interface Parent {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface Child {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  parent: string
}
```

And I have the following endpoints:

```
/api/parents              #GET (list of parents), POST (create new parent)
/api/parents/<PARENT_ID>  #GET, PATCH, PUSH, DELETE (a single parent)
/api/children             #GET (list of children), POST (create new child)
/api/children/<CHILD_ID>  #GET, PATCH, PUSH, DELETE (a single child)
/api/families             #GET (all parents and children)
```

`/api/families` is a convenience function, that returns all parents and children in the format:

```js
{
  parents: Parent[];
  children: Child[];
}
```

In the past, I have made a separate `families` entry for my ngrx store with just loading/loaded parameters, then a set of `LoadFamilies` actions to grab the data from the server.  I then include those actions in my Parents and Children store reducers, and act on them appropriately.  What I want to do now is add this additional reducer to my existing ngrx/data controlled entities.  Any thoughts/example code on how to go about this?

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: Unfortunately, not using ngrx/data.  I did find another similar library, [auto-entity](https://briebug.gitbook.io/ngrx-auto-entity/), which handles simple stuff in a similar way to ngrx/data, but offers a lot more flexibility (at least documented) for doing more complex things like what I was trying to do in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Extend `DefaultDataService` see https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice#custom-entitydataservice

Within a pipe map nested data to entities (I use normalizr)

Then dispatch entity cache action(s) using `EntityActionFactory as eaFactory` to update store as you see fit

example with Parent <--> Child of ConcreteRecordHeader <--> ConcreteRecordLoad

```
  getById(key: string | number): Observable<ConcreteRecordHeader> {
    return super.getById(key).pipe(
      map((denorm: any) =>
        this.categoryCacheService.normalizeCategory([denorm])
      ),
      tap((norm: NormalizedCategories) => this.mergeQuerySet(norm)),
      map((norm: NormalizedCategories) => this.pickEntities(norm)[0])
    ) as Observable<ConcreteRecordHeader>;
  }

  protected mergeQuerySet(norm: NormalizedCategories) {
    console.log("⚠️ Merging server data ⚠️");
    const options: EntityActionOptions = {
      mergeStrategy: MergeStrategy.PreserveChanges
    };
    const data = norm.entities.concreteRecordLoads
      ? Object.values(norm.entities.concreteRecordLoads)
      : [];
    const action = this.eaFactory.create(
      "ConcreteRecordLoad",
      EntityOp.SAVE_UPSERT_MANY_SUCCESS,
      data,
      options
    );
    this.entityCacheDispatcher.dispatch(action);
  }

  protected pickEntities(norm: NormalizedCategories) {
    return (norm.entities.concreteRecordHeaders
      ? Object.values(norm.entities.concreteRecordHeaders)
      : []) as ConcreteRecordHeader[];
  }
```

Sadly `this.entityCacheDispatcher.mergeQuerySet()` isn't working with mergeStrategy which is the natural API to use. I plan on submitting a PR for this.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect that such a basic thing would be so hard to find.